# Evaluating the integral $\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2}\sin(\xi x)\ dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have been trying to evaluate this integral:$$\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2}\sin(\xi x)\ dx$$
But I seem to be a little bit stuck on how to do this. I have tried partial integration by taking derivatives of $x\sin(\xi x)$ or $xe^{-x^2}$, but both times I arrived at an integral that seemed even harder to solve. An idea that kind of worked was to use the series representation of $\sin(\xi x)$ and then interchanging the summation with the integral. In that case, I would not know if the interchange is viable though ( I could not really find an integrable upper bound to use dominated convergence).

Any hints on how the interchange with summation would work or any other approach would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hint: your  integral is the derivative of the real part of the fourier transform of a gaussian with respect to frequency

Comment: @tired Actually, thats how I arrived here since I wanted to evaluate the fourier transform. Was that a step backwards?

Comment: the searched resuld should be this here $$\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\pi } e^{-\frac{\xi ^2}{4}} \xi$$

Comment: @Jack4t3 the FT of a Gaussian is usually shown using the completition of the square in the exponent. and yes i think your approach might go a little bit in a not so useful direction ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With integrating by parts 
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2}\sin(\xi x)\ dx
&= \dfrac{\xi}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\cos(\xi x)\ dx \\
&= \dfrac{\xi}{2}{\bf Re}\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}e^{i\xi x}\ dx \\
&= \dfrac{\xi}{2}{\bf Re}\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-\frac12\xi i)^2-\frac14\xi^2}\ dx \\
&= \dfrac{\xi}{2}e^{-\frac14\xi^2}{\bf Re}\int_0^\infty e^{-(x-\frac12\xi i)^2}\ dx \\
&= \dfrac{\xi}{2}e^{-\frac14\xi^2}\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

Here is a real way of arguing, that is a bit longer, but still. If you define
$$
f(\xi)=-\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos(\xi x)\,dx
$$
then your integral is $f'(\xi)$.

But using parity arguments, we find that
$$
\begin{align}
f'(\xi)&=\int_0^{+\infty} xe^{-x^2}\sin(\xi x)\,d x\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xe^{-x^2}\bigl(\sin(\xi x)+\cos(\xi x)\bigr)\,dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\biggl[\frac{d}{dx}\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2}e^{-x^2}\bigl(\sin(\xi x)+\cos(\xi x)\bigr)\Bigr)+\frac{\xi}{2}e^{-x^2}\bigl(\cos(\xi x)-\sin(\xi x)\bigr)\biggr]\,dx\\
&=\frac{\xi}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\bigl(\cos(\xi x)-\sin(\xi x)\bigr)\,dx\\
&=\frac{\xi}{4}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\cos(\xi x)\,dx\\
&=-\frac{\xi}{2}f(\xi).
\end{align}
$$
Hence
$$
f(\xi)=Ce^{-\xi^2/4}
$$
for some constant $C$. But
$$
C=f(0)=-\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}\,dx=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2},
$$
so
$$
f(\xi)=-\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}e^{-\xi^2/4}.
$$
Differentiating, we find that
$$
f'(\xi)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\xi e^{-\xi^2/4}.
$$